# Integration Mantis BugTracker with Jira

Tags: jira, mantis

I am trying to establish 2-way integration between Mantis and Jira .

What I mean 2-way integration:
I can create a ticket (eg a bug/support contact etc) from Mantis in Jira.

If I update (eg, adding a comment or changing the status etc) that ticket in Jira, Mantis will get automatically updated with the changes.
If I update in Mantis, Jira will get automatically updated.

Is this possible to be done in Mantis? Do you have an already built Plug-in for this functionality? If there is a plugin can someone please provide me the link to download.

Thanks & Regards,
Srikanth P

Answer (score 0):

244/5000
Hi, I think that's not possible Maybe only by several adjustments. You can possibly solve this via the respective import functions?

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/importing-data-from-mantis-938847610.html